# Can this be done with django __str__ method?

Tags: python, django, model

I have 2 models with foreignkey to a model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.description

class Model1(models.Model):
    mymodel = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)

class Model2(models.Model):
    mymodel = model.ForeignKey(MyModel)
```

In the drop down list in the admin for `mymodel` field the **str** method returns description of MyModel
How do I change what is returned for each model `Model1`,`Model2` 
example in the **str** method to return 'type' if the model is Model2 or 'description' if model is Model1.

What am basically asking is how to conditionally return either "type" or "description" in MyModel

Answer (score 0):

Personally i don't like this solution.

`ForeignKey` represents many to one relation. And you want to reach it reversed.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    def __str__(self):
        if self.model1_set.exists():
            return self.type
        if self.model2_set.exists():
            return self.description
        # What to return if both exists or none of them?
```

Comment: Your method returns the method on "list display" after save

Comment: @Martins ah, I misunderstood. You want it for `MyModel` to change `__str__` output based existence of `Model1` or `Model2`?

Comment: that is what i meant.

Comment: @Martins I've edited the answer check if it satisfies you

Comment: both model returns empty

Comment: to your comment both exists I just want to use type for model2 and description for model1

Comment: Show me the admin code you use. I'm afraid we are still not on the same page.

Comment: @Martins if both models exists we are not able do tell which value to return in `__str__`